# How to make overlap detection more accurate?

Tags: unreal-4, overlay

I have a project where there are two types of warrior, red and blue.

When they overlap, both are destroyed, or at least that is what should happen.

**Red Warrior Blueprint (code of destruction):**

[image]

This overlap is not detected. I put an impression right after the **Cast To** and it does not appear, **so the event is not detected**.

*Which makes me think of another question I asked, maybe I have found the answer for it ([Error detecting collision with another instance of the same actor?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172514/error-detecting-collision-with-another-instance-of-the-same-actor)).*

**Capsule Collision of Warriors:**

[image]

**I had a similar problem in the collision of the red warrior with a tower, in order to have the detection of the overlap I had to greatly increase the capsule collision of tower:**

[image]

It's practically a sphere.

The correct title of the question should be => **How to make overlap detection more accurate without having to increase the collision box?**

But I do not rule out that increasing the collision box is not the best way to detect overlap, I just want you to explain why (if it is).

---

**EDIT 1 (attempt based on Stephen's comment)**

I put an impression when the cast fails.

**Red Warrior Blueprint and Blue Warrior Blueprint (respectively):**

[image]

**Result in game:**

[image]

Test made with capsule in size (sclae) => x = 1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.5.

---

**EDIT 2 (Event image)**

**Image to show how the overlay is called:**

[image]

Comment: To confirm the cast is failing, pull off the Cast Failed execution pin use a Print String.

Comment: I did, the overlap is not detected.

Comment: There's your issue.  What is to the left of the cast?  I'm guessing it's the OnBeginOverlap event but what pin are you pulling off that to plug into the cast?

Comment: Exactly, I added one more image to the question, which may help in the understanding.